# Self Invoking Functions, Resharper 6.1 and JS Lint - Possible to be Valid For Both?

Tags: javascript, jslint, resharper-6.1

Say I have a bit of JavaScript that looks like this:

```
MyCompany.MyProduct = {};

(function () {

    "use strict";

    MyCompany.MyProduct.doSomethingAmazing = function () {
    };
}());
```

which I believe is an OK approach to take...

It passes [Mr Crockford's](http://www.crockford.com/) Javascript [lint](http://www.jslint.com) so I figured I was onto a good thing but then I noticed that [Resharper](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/12/resharper-61-improvements-in-intellisense-options/) (6.1 running in Visual Studio 2010) told me

> Unexpected Expression

on the last line (i.e. this bit: `}());`).

Now, I know there is a controversial bracket placement there and many prefer the form `})();` but that does not appease [Resharper](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/12/resharper-61-improvements-in-intellisense-options/) and it annoys [JS Lint](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/12/resharper-61-improvements-in-intellisense-options/) so I let that drop.

Then I went for:

```
MyCompany.MyProduct = {};

!function () {

    "use strict";

    MyCompany.MyProduct.doSomethingAmazing = function () {
    };
}();
```

which I think is equivalent (according to [this](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/) anyway) and Resharper seemed happy but now JS Lint is freaking out, telling me:

> Wrap an immediate function invocation in parentheses to assist the reader in understanding that the expression is the result of a function, and not the function itself.

So, before I just select one style (probably the one that annoys both the squabbling parties because if they can't play together...) I was wondering, since Javascript has so many neat syntactical alleyways if you know where to shine the torch:

**Is there any syntax that I can use that will keep both parties happy?**

Comment: http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: I hear ya, Neil. This is an old question but there's a new tool called ESLint that may help. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot satisfy two opposites at once. But there are workarounds...

[JSLint](http://jslint.com) requires you to [move the invocation into the parens that contain the function](http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2011/02/15/jslint-messages-move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function/). As an alternative to JSLint you can try [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) or [ESLint](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/16/introducing-eslint/), with similar but more flexible rules. ESLint in particular allows you to set the option [wrap-iife](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/wrap-iife.html) to either "inside" or "outside." [Here's an example](http://jslinterrors.com/move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function/).

Or, you could try to change the rules used by Resharper. I don't know what options Resharper gives you for that, since I haven't used it, but it might be worth looking up.